# Add another "action" in one activity

Tags: android

I know im green user.
I have an activity with webview and a button.
I want to go to next activity when i pressed a button but i dont know how.
When user click button, he will be "teleported" to MainActivity.

There is code:
Help guys!

```
    package musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main10Activity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

        Button button2;

       {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main10);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView6);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);



    }


    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main10);
        button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main10Activity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: In order to get help, write a more detailed question - what's not working? Give examples.

Comment: When I press a button its not working, its totaly nothing

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem in your code is that you don't `Override` the functions you should override.

Try adding the following phraze: `@Override` before the `OnClickListener`
 initalization line, which is: `public void onClick(View v){...`

This `@Override` declaration should be also used before other functions such as `onBackPressed`, because you want to create your own implementation to these functions and not to perform the function from the `super` class (that your listener, for example, inherits from).

Answer (score 0):

Override onclick method inside the OnClickListener

excuse typos, sent from mobile

Answer (score 0):

To get the intent working, try removing setContentView(R.layout.activity_main10); on line 20 since the view is already set in onCreate.

Because the onClickListener is set in onCreate, it is already going to be run by the program, so adding another @Override there won't help, but you should add @Override before the backPress & menu methods as instructed in other answers. That said, not having @Override on the menu methods should not prevent the intent from working.

Comment: To test, remove the setContentView on line 20 and run again. If it still doesn't work try to comment out all the code except for the onCreate method. Leaving this should allow you to isolate the onClick and intent to see if they work, which they should because the structure is correct as far as I can tell